# pass data to my model class from service provider through bindings

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection

I am trying to pass the variable called `$variable` to the class called `Book` which is model
so that I can use that variable from my web `middleware` so far I have done this in my `AppServiceProvider.php`

```
        $data = [
            'exchange_rate' => 1,
            'currency_prefix' => 'Rs',
        ];
        $this->app->bind('App\Models\FrontEnd\Book', function ($app) use ($data) {
            return new Book($data);
        });
```

And In my `Book.php`

```
public $data;
public function __construct($data) 
{
      $this->data = $data
}
```

But i am getting this error ..

```
Too few arguments to function App\Models\FrontEnd\Book::__construct(), 0 passed in      
/home/vagrant/sites/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasRelationships.php on line 720 and exactly 1 expected.
```

Comment: $this->data = $book

Comment: its $data sorry I wrote $book mistakely but error is still there

Comment: why are you trying to do this, how does this data relate to the model ... what are you actually trying to accomplish ... why do you think you need to pass this data, etc etc